# metal.js does not build through npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, metal.js

My gut tells me the problem has to do with node.js and npm. I was following a quick start guide from metal.js. There are very little resources online.

Here is the link: http://metaljs.com/docs/

In the terminal, I was able to navigate to the folder to `1. Hello World` and create its npm dependencies, by typing: `sudo npm i`, but I could not build the `demos/index.html` file by typing `npm run build` in the same directory.

I have the latest install on node.js and npm. I am using a mac and for metal.js I am using boilerplated with JSX provided.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `generator-metal` installed?

Comment: npm -v generator-metal
3.10.10

Comment: Try installing globally `npm -g generator-metal`

Comment: I followed this ---> https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-metal
but it would not build index.html for "hello world" message.

Comment: Really need help on this, any input greatly appreciated